# Cause TFS InvokeProcess Build Activity to run under other credentials

Tags: tfs, powershell, tfsbuild

We have customized the build process with a InvokeProcess action that runs a powershell script that deploys our sln.

Problem is that this script must be run under a given user (not the tfsbuild user).

How can we achive this?

- Alternative 1: Make the InvokeProcess
  run as a different user -
- Alternative 2: Make the powershell script itself
  run as different user

Problem is that I have no idea of how to do any of this.

Answer (score 3):

I have created a blog post on this how you can achieve this: [Customize Team Build 2010 – Part 9: Impersonate activities (run under other credentials)](http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/05/27/Customize-Team-Build-2010-e28093-Part-9-Impersonate-activities-(run-under-other-credentials).aspx)

Comment: Thanks! I'm new to the wwf and the custom build process. Could you briefly outline the steps to start using your code? Should I build a dll? Place it where? Call it from the where? I'm using the InvokeProcess activity block, guess I should call this block from within the using block, but how? Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: You can find those answers in the rest of the series: http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/?tag=/build+2010+customization

Comment: ok, thanks. I think I got most of the answers, but I can't figure out why we need to create a Template project (part 4). Should it not be enough to create a new codeactivity, then add it to the toolbox (choose item) and start using it? (and of course on the build controller add a path). Can't understand whats happening with the template project. Thanks for any clarification.

Comment: To be able to add codeactivity to the template, creating the template project is the easiest. If you find another way of adding the code actvity, you can use that also. I always do in this way and it works perfectly. Everything is included in one solution which makes the development easy. (although the debugging experience is not optimal)

Answer (score 2):

A pure PowerShell option, assuming you have PowerShell 2.0 on your TeamBuild machine, is to use a background job.  Start-Job allows you to specify the credentials of another account to perform the work. After spinning up the background job in your script you will probably want to wait for the job to finish and grab the results to output from the main script e.g.:

```
$cred = Get-Credential
$job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock { ls c:\windows\system32 -r *.sys } -Cred $cred
Wait-Job $job
Receive-Job $job
```

With respect to capturing, storing and retrieving the credentials, see this [blog post for a good treatise](http://www.leeholmes.com/blog/2008/06/04/importing-and-exporting-credentials-in-powershell/) on the subject.