# Forcing App Pool recycle or Website Restart during Team Build with automated website publishing

Tags: asp.net, tfsbuild, msdeploy

I've been struggling while trying to create an automated TFS 2010 team build that uses MSDeploy to deploy the website to one of our local boxes. Aside from not being able to find good documentation, a large part of the problem is that the site uses a native C++ dll. I've managed to get things almost working now and the site will deploy during the build BUT the native dll is typically in use and prevents the deployment if the site has been accessed since the last restart. I would like to have the build force an application pool recycle or restart the site/application just prior to deploying the files to the remote server. I can use the following at the command prompt to achieve this manually:

```
msdeploy -verb:sync -source:recycleApp -dest:recycleApp="Default Web Site/Application",computerName="MyServer"
```

How do I hook this into the build process so that it occurs before the publishing pipeline tries to copy files to the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the InvokeProcess activity in your workflow. You can then invoke a batch script that would contain your command line above.

You can drag the activity and insert it as the step before publishing (assuming you are using the workflow designer).

If you need the script to run as another user there are plenty of helpful suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749769/tfs-invokeprocess-to-run-under-other-credentials) and in the linked blog.

I already owe SO and Ewald for getting our TFS build up and running.

Comment: I did get this working the way you prescribed. It's not exactly how I wanted to do it (I'd rather add a hook in the .proj file that runs at the right time) but it did get me over the hurdle and I even made it parameterized. Thanks for your help!